# Change the content of the "Active" tooltip

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tooltips, questions-tabs

When you hover over the "Active" tab, the tooltip displays following:

> Questions that have been asked, answered, or updated recently

How about changing it to:

> Questions that have been asked, answered, or **modified** recently

The reason for this little UI change is to keep the content of the tooltip as *contextual* as possible based on the actual usage of the term that has been applied to the question. All of the questions are currently labeled with their "last activity" status by using one of the following:

- asked
- answered
- modified

Notice the "**modified**" and not "updated".

I know that the word "updated" is synonym to "modified" and self-explanatory. But, just thought of making it little bit tidier based on the current usage of the "modified" status. Is it possible to make this tiny UI change?

Please share your thoughts.

**P.S.**

Here is yet another reason for using "modified" status label. This is taken from the comment posted by Shog9 (♦ moderator) on my question: [Moderator ♦ “modified” question does not match to inside “edited” by username and timestamp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260608/moderator-%E2%99%A6-modified-question-does-not-match-to-inside-edited-by-username-an)

> "Modified" is a broad term that covers many different changes to a
>   post. Edits modify the post, but so do other changes.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could apply this.

When you update something, you really is just making the post up-to-date to today's status. When you modify the post, you actually change the post to fix errors in grammar or formatting, not just replacing the old stuff with the new. This also will fit in the usual list of words used in the `Active` tab in which you said: asked, answered, or modified.