# Moderator ♦ "modified" question does not match to inside "edited" by username and timestamp

Tags: support, bump, homepage, last-activity

I just noticed a strange thing about the mis-match of the question's "last activity" status (i.e. *modified* in this case). To illustrate this better, I would like to include the following screenshots.

- The main page of Meta.SE shows the question [New navigation, alpha 2 released](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259220/new-navigation-alpha-2-released) was `modified 24 mins ago Sklivvz ♦`

  > [image]
- Whereas, upon visiting to question, it shows (in the question status area) as `edited Jul 3 at 0:27 David Fullerton ♦`

  > [image]

The standard way (from the post) to find out any updates made to post is to click on the "edited" link, but this time I did not bother to click on it as the given date/timestamp and displayed user name (as shown in the above screenshot) did not match to what was shown on the main page. I am clueless here.

So, out of curiosity, I decided to check on Sklivvz latest activity and guess what, nothing shows there about this question was edited by him today. Here is the screenshot of [Sklivvz activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131112/sklivvz?tab=activity&sort=all) (all actions)

> [image]

As you can see from the above screenshot, the latest activity made by Sklivvz was a comment `Let’s improve our site navigation` which was made on the `Jul 4` (or *2015-07-04 15:09:09Z* to be precise).

So, I am really confused here. Why does the question on the main page of Meta.SE is labeled with "modified" status when nothing was "modified" by Sklivvz at all (based on the facts shown in the screenshots above). Does diamond moderators have a secret method/ weapon by which they can update the question without leaving any trails of edit i.e. leaving the "edited" status (by who and when in the question status area) unchanged.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: The mod reopened the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard so just opening question by mod can push to main page? Why? Is this to self promote?

Comment: Reopened questions *always* bump, @HackerKarma - regardless of who reopens them. This is to allow the community to review the reopened question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard then this bump should not be called as "modified". We need a new status label e.g. "reopened" .... It's confusing.

Comment: "Modified" is a broad term that covers many different changes to a post. Edits modify the post, but so do other changes.

Comment: @Shog9 can you please share link to any published docs/reference that says about moderators "reopened" power?

Comment: @HackerKarma it's not a mod only power. Any user who can close a question (3k rep on graduated sites and OP) can also cast a Reopen vote. 5 of those, and a closed question is reopened.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is there any way to check/validate that 5 of the votes were actually cast before re-opening this question? Any screenshot, may be?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is clear message, in this specific case there was one single vote, but since it was cast by a user with moderator power (developer, to be exact) it was binding.

Comment: @ShadowWizard with one single vote? and from moderator power (developer, to be exact)? Do you mean to say "any employee / core team" with moderator ability can do this magic? Could you please provide me a FAQ link or any published doc that gives all the info.

Comment: Sorry this is really basic... moderator can open/close/delete anything with a single vote.

Comment: You might benefit from reading through the [help center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help). A lot of this is already in there. In particular, [this page answers your questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: @Emrakul Thanks. I did read that but trying to find an answer on "reopening"question without giving any reasons when the question is NOT  improved/refined at all. That's what my main aim behind posting this question. Also, can't understand it took 5 users to close the question as a "off-topic" but same user(moderator) can over-rule with single-vote to re-open it.  But, that's the separate question and I will dig more on it.

Comment: @HackerKarma there's nothing to dig. Anybody with a diamond on their username (a moderator or developer) can open, close, edit, lock, unlock, delete, undelete, or mark as spam any post at any time unilaterally. If moderators needed 4 other people to agree in order to do anything, it would really defeat the point of having moderators.

Comment: Same way as with downvotes/upvotes etc, nobody is forced to comment why he/she cast a reopen vote. In your specific case the OP happens to be SE employee/developer with a diamond so he chose to overrule our closing (yes, I was part of this) and this is his full right. While I disagree with it, can't fight it - it's legit use of his privileges.

Comment: @nhinkle not an issue there... I am after the "modified" status which confused me.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess I have to admit the defeat here as I am getting downvotes -- You quotes "While I disagree with it, can't fight it - it's legit use of his privileges" is what I take

Comment: You get downvotes because you turned your question into a total mess, consisting of several totally different questions, with different answers. You can still roll back to the original question, and some downvotes might be undone.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am a newbie and this is big lesson and I learned something new. Anyway, I have removed the EDIT section. It's back to the original state where I got an upvote.

Comment: Cheers, looking OK now. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can cause a question to be bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)

Comment: @gnat I have removed the reference to "bumped", please see the edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was reopened by Sklivvz.

[image: see revision history]

This is visible in the question's revision history, but does not show up on Sklivvz' Activity page, as reopen votes show up on the Votes page, which is not publicly accessible.

Questions are always bumped to the front page when reopened, regardless of who reopens them. This is done to allow the community to take a second look at the question, potentially providing an answer (or re-closing).

Comment: You beat me by 1 second! Congrats :)

Comment: @Dronehinge I am the master ninja. None can beat me at my game. :]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I see the Reopened status BUT, then shouldn't it go to review queue to get 5 votes cast before re-opening? Is there any screenshot of this review queue? OR diamond moderator does not need 5 votes cast to reopen the question?

Comment: @HackerKarma Moderators have binding votes (either to open or to close).

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you. As you can see I have learned very hard way what "modified" status actually means and what it doesn't. My question will surely help some newbies out there who may get confused like me. "Binding votes" is the key term.

Comment: @HackerKarma You may also find this helpful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role

Comment: @AnnaLear That was an excellent post. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

No bug here.

Sklivvz reopened the question 24 minutes ago.. (well 1 hour+ ago now)

[image]

> Then my question is why push it to main page? and that too stating it was "modified"

As commented by Shog [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260608/moderator-%E2%99%A6-modified-question-does-not-match-to-inside-edited-by-username-an#comment849675_260608)

> This is to allow the community to review the reopened question.

and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260608/moderator-%E2%99%A6-modified-question-does-not-match-to-inside-edited-by-username-an#comment849682_260608)

> "Modified" is a broad term that covers many different changes to a post. Edits modify the post, but so do other changes.

Comment: Then my question is why push it to main page? and that too stating it was "modified"

Comment: @HackerKarma It's pushed to the main page so everyone can review it. Questions are nominally reopened when they've been improved/refined enough that it's worth giving them a second pass.

Comment: @Emrakul see my comment to ShadowWizard on the question, don't want to repeat the same everywhere

Comment: @Emrakul Also, what do you mean by "improved/refined enough"? How do you do that just by "reopening" the question?

Comment: @Hacker When a question is closed, it can later be reopened by five users. This happens predominantly when the question has been edited by the author to significantly improve its content. In such cases, if it's reopened, it's worth bumping to the top so everyone can take another look.

Comment: @Emrakul but that's about "Closed" question right? Then, I can understand. But where do see this question was "closed" before?

Comment: @HackerKarma it's all in the revisions list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks. I have added more details in the EDIT section of my question.

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea @HackerKarma since this is totally different question than what you asked originally, and it's all covered in [this faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) - sorry for not posting it before, thought you'll find it by searching a bit.

Comment: @HackerKarma also, there's no such thing "super moderator" - the developers get the same power as moderators (hence the diamond), plus set of abilities not related to moderation, which isn't published anywhere, but it doesn't make them "super mods". Like I said before, Close/Reopen are part of basic moderation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks again. I EDITed my question. Also, read my comment to Emrakul. Trying to avoid dupes...