# Display "recent activity" type for the Active tab questions on Mobile UI

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, mobile-web

The current main page of Meta.SE on the mobile website lists all the "active" questions without the mention of what **type of recent activity** was actually took place for those questions to become an *active* ones. The Active tab tooltip message says, the active questions are those "Questions that have been asked, answered, or updated<sup>1</sup> recently".

Here is how the current mobile webpage looks like:

> [image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, there is *no way* one can tell if these questions were recently **asked**, **answered** or **modified**. It just tells you how long ago the question had a recent activity and the user who triggered it. That's it.

**Reasons why this change is important:**

- As of now one has to open the question and scroll down to the question-status area in order to know the type of recent activity was made. That's an extra step to perform. And, its very annoying especially on the *lengthy* questions where you have to swipe n number of times to get to the question-status area. This is not *intuitive* at all.
- Due the unavailability of **answered** activity link under the question, we have no option but to tap the question. Upon tapping, it always takes you to the *top* of that question instead of taking to that answer *directly*. I can understand if there was *only one* answer but what if there were *multiple* answers along with tons of comments on it. For example, if someone post an answer on a featured question like this: [Upcoming login changes...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live), then it will surely annoy you as now you have to scroll n number of times to reach to it. This is not *intuitive* at all either.
- We can literally apply the above "answered" point explanation for the **modified** activity link too. Here, upon tapping, it will take you directly to the "modified" post.
- As for the **asked** goes, just link it to the question itself.

I would like to make a feature request to display the "type of recent activity" such as **asked**, **answered** or **modified** (with a link, as stated in the above points) for all of the Active tab questions on the mobile UI. There is enough room in front of the time shown to display (without cluttering) the *type* of recent activity made. This will also make it *consistent* with the other user interfaces.

Please share your thoughts.

Here is a **mock-up** version: (Please ignore the font.)

> [image]

**updated**<sup>1</sup> - Although the Active tab tooltip message shows "updated" but the current used/applied term is **modified**. I hope some day the current [Active tab tooltip message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260551/change-the-content-of-the-active-tooltip) gets changed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see you removed the "design" tab, could you please explain why it does not suits here. I added it because if this feature-request gets implemented, then SE team has to tweak the current mobile UI design. Hence the "design" tag. May be "user-interface" right tag here as it does deals with input i.e. click from user. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Well, "design" tag is mainly for CSS changes, i.e. changing how things that already exist look like. Moving stuff to different place or adding new feature to a page isn't task to the SE design team.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks. What about "user-interface" tag? As it does deals with input i.e. click from user.

Comment: Yes, this might fit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks would you mind adding it as you high-reps and chances of denial are less.

Comment: As a fyi, the main interface uses a link to `/?lastactivity` for answer and modified, a link to the question for asked. You just want it to work exactly how the main interface works, and I agree it should. +1